# I've made a setup for my program to run on other pc's, I cant make the connectionstring work, the error is "constring has not been initialized"

Tags: vb.net

Here i am trying to make a connection to the database and install it in the target pc and also create a connectionstring that would work with any other computer. Any help is much appreciated

```
Private Function GetSql(ByVal Name As String) As String
    Try

        ' Gets the current assembly.
        Dim Asm As [Assembly] = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()

        ' Resources are named using a fully qualified name.
        Dim strm As Stream = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(
          Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name)

        ' Reads the contents of the embedded file.
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strm)
        Return reader.ReadToEnd()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("In GetSQL: " & ex.Message)
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub ExecuteSql(ByVal DatabaseName As String, ByVal Sql As String)
    Dim Command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, masterConnection)

    Dim myConn As SqlConnection

    myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=1500")


    ' Initialize the connection, open it, and set it to the "master" database
    masterConnection.ConnectionString = myConn.ConnectionString

    Command.Connection.Open()
    Command.Connection.ChangeDatabase(DatabaseName)
    Try
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Finally
        ' Closing the connection should be done in a Finally block
        Command.Connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub AddDBTable(ByVal strDBName As String)
    Try
        ' Creates the database.
        ExecuteSql("master", "CREATE DATABASE " + strDBName)

        ' Creates the tables.
        ExecuteSql(strDBName, GetSql("sql.txt"))

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Reports any errors and abort.
        MsgBox("In exception handler: " & ex.Message)
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub Install(
    ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)

    MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
    AddDBTable(Me.Context.Parameters.Item("dbname"))
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not specifying a data source so how could it connect to any data source? What data source do you want to connect to? If it's supposed to be the default instance on the local machine then use "." or "(local)" as the data source in the connection string.

Comment: Now i get an error saying "Incorrect sytnax near "DATABASE"

Comment: If you're getting a syntax error executing SQL code then you have obviously connected successfully, so the question you asked here is now answered. If you have a different question (you do) then post an answer to this one here and then post a new question elsewhere, with all and only the information relevant to that question.

Comment: ExecuteSql could look more like `Sub ExecuteSql(ByVal databaseName As String, ByVal sql As String)` `Using con As New SqlConnection($"Data Source=;Initial Catalog={databaseName};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=1500")` `con.Open` `New SqlCommand(sql, con).ExecuteNonQuery()` `End Sub` i.e. 3 lines in the Sub

Comment: @jmcilhinney you should post your answer below, so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a data source, i.e. a server and, optionally, an instance to connect to. We don't know what that would be in your specific case but, if you want to connect to the default SQL Server instance on the local machine then you can use "." or "(local)" and it will work anywhere.